# SQLite extensions in BIRT

Tags: database, sqlite, birt

I have an Sqlite database local copy file (file.db). I am trying to make reports using BIRT. I have connected the data to BIRT using JDBC driver for SQLite. The problem is that in the SQLite database, we rely on .dll extensions to load views for the tables. How do I load that extension into BIRT to be able to see and work with the views?

Thanks

Comment: Can you just redo the logic for the views in BIRT? Then you could just use a standard SQLite driver.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user3660637. I am new to BIRt and do not know/understand as to what you mean by redo the logic. I have found a different approach to solve the problem as my company does not need the complete data. So i will be exporting some of the data from a table as csv and then using it to create reports.